# Assign numbers to pods in a replica?

Tags: kubernetes

Consider the following yaml file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello-world
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello-world
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello-world
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello-world-pod
        image: d33tah/chinese-tones:latest
        ports: 
        - containerPort: 80
        - containerPort: 5000
        - containerPort: 443
        resources:
            limits:
                cpu: 250m
            requests:
                cpu: 250m
```

I'd like the two replicas to somehow be numbered and have that information exposed through environment variables, so that one of them knows that it's number one and the other one that it's number two (or zero). Is this use case supported in Kubernetes?

Comment: check out `statefulset`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I was looking for a StatefulSet instead of a Deployment. Here's the documentation:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/

By default, StatefulSet assigns predictable 0-indexed pod numbers. It's accessible through the pod's hostname.